# The requested resource does not support http method

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Meu código:

```
        var data = JSON.stringify(orderNo)
        options.path = "/1/sales?merchantOrderId=" + orderNo 
        options.method = 'GET';
        console.log(options)

        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {

            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                var retornoIds = iconv.decode(chunk, 'utf-8');
                console.log(retornoIds)   
                }
            });

        });
        req.write(data)
        req.on('error', function (err) {
            callback(err);
        });

        req.end();
```

Meu options:

```
{ hostname: 'apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br',
  port: 443,
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  headers:
  { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    MerchantId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    MerchantKey: 'xxxxxxxxx' },
  path: '/1/sales?merchantOrderId=VE805051701',
  method: 'GET' }
```

Não sei o que tem de errado

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

Comment: A mensagem já diz tudo Erick. Checou se o end-point aceita GET nessa url? Uma dica é testar antes pelo Postman

Comment: Eu estou seguindo a documentação da cielo, e lá diz que para fazer a consulta devo fazer um get exatamente assim, isto foi o que me deixou muito confuso, principalmente porque semana passada estava funcionando, vou tentar usar o Postman.

Comment: Achei meu erro, o hostname está como 'apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br', este é para requisiçoes para consulta deve ser 'apiquerysandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br'.

Comment: Que bom @ErickZanetti =]